# navigator.onLine siempre me regresa true o online

Tags: javascript, electron

Estoy tratando de que mi `app` de `electron` detecte la conexión a `wifi` para avisar de cambios en ella. Ej:

> Se desconecta la red y lanza un aviso o redirige a otro `.html`.

Pero por alguna razón siempre me regresa `true` u `Online`

este es mi código:

```js
 if (navigator.onLine) {
  console.log('online');
} else {
  console.log('offline');
}
```

Tambien probé con [Online/Offline](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/online-offline-events)

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
  const alertOnlineStatus = () => {
    window.alert(navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline')
  }

  window.addEventListener('online',  alertOnlineStatus)
  window.addEventListener('offline',  alertOnlineStatus)

  alertOnlineStatus()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

y obtengo el mismo resultado.

¿Alguien tiene idea de que puede estar pasando?

Comment: `99.99%` seguro de que hay alguna otra interfaz activa ... como, por ejemplo, `lo` (interfaz de red local). La documentación indica `... si realmente desea determinar el estado de acceso a Internet de Electron, debe desarrollar medios adicionales para verificar.`. Te sugeriría, como método *indoloro*, que realices un `ping` o mejor aún, un intento de conexión con [`HTTP GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) a una dirección conocida, como `www.google.com`.

Comment: @Trauma me podrias mostrar un ejemplo de ambos casos?